# Anyone have a way to tokenize a paragraph, put each sentence into a pandas data frame, and perform sentiment analysis on each?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, nlp, data-science

Beginner NLP/python programmer. Title says it all. I basically need a code that will tokenize a paragraph, perform sentiment analysis on each sentence put each sentence along with it's rating on a pandas data frame. I already have code that can tokenize a paragraph and even perform sentiment analysis, but I'm struggling with putting both into a data frame. Thus far, I have:

I used newspaper3k to extract the url and text.

```
from newspaper import fulltext
import requests
url = "https://www.click2houston.com/news/local/2021/06/18/houston-water-wastewater-proposed-increase-this-is-what-mayor-sylvester-turner-wants-you-to-know/"
text = fulltext(requests.get(url).text)
```

Then I used the BERT extractive summarizer to summarize the article text.

```
models = Summarizer()
result = models(text, min_length=30)
full = "".join(result)
type(full)
```

Then I tokenized the summary into sentences using nltk.

```
tokens=sent_tokenize(full)
print(type(np.array(tokens)[0]))
```

Lastly, I put it into a basic dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(tokens), columns=['sentences'])
```

The only thing I'm missing is the sentiment analysis. I simply need a sentiment analysis (preferably from BERT) rating on each sentence implemented into the data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/transformers/quicktour.html) allows you to do what you want

```
from transformers import pipeline
from newspaper import fulltext
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
url = "https://www.click2houston.com/news/local/2021/06/18/houston-water-wastewater-proposed-increase-this-is-what-mayor-sylvester-turner-wants-you-to-know/"
text = fulltext(requests.get(url).text)
texts = [item.strip() for item in text.split('\n')[:10] if item.strip()]
summarizer = pipeline("summarization")
sentiment_analyser = pipeline('sentiment-analysis')
sumerize = lambda text:simmarizer(text, min_length=5, max_length=30)
sentiment_analyse = lambda sentiment_analyser:snt(text)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(texts), columns=['lines'])
df['Summarized'] = df.lines.apply(summarizer)
df['Sentiment'] = df.lines.apply(sentiment_analyser)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Very, very late here, but thank you for your response, this worked like a charm and helped me learn about the 'lambda' functions. Appreciate it once again!

Answer (score 0):

use a transformers pipelines

both sentiment and Summarization pipelines exist

https://huggingface.co/course/chapter1/3?fw=pt